# Shortcut to application form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working with a third party application, which is installed locally on my PC.  The application allows you to create a shortcut on your PC as follows:

nds://1

This will open person 1 in the local application.  Is nds a protocol like HTTP and FILE?

I want to create a hyperlink on an ASP.NET webpage, which points to: nds://{PersonNo), however when I click on the hyperlink the application opens and I am prompted with an error:

Windows Internet Explorer says: Unable to open this helper application for nds://1.

```
The protocol specified in this address is not valid.  Make sure the address is valid and try again.
```

Comment: Check out [asynchronous pluggable protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Sam Axe, thanks.  Do you know the reason for the error when?

Comment: nope.  I'm not familiar with the `nds://` protocol, nor the application that is supposed to handle it.